# How to find position (x and y separately) of an element in a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to find the position of an element in a matrix (every element is unique).

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work properly:

```
coords = list()

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if(matrix[i][j] == a):
            coords.insert(0, i)
            coords.insert(1, j)
        if(matrix[i][j] == b):
            coords.insert(2, i)
            coords.insert(3, j)   

print(coords)
```

Example:

> Matrix:
>
> ```
> T U E S A
> B C D F G 
> H I K L M 
> N O P Q R
> V W X Y Z
> ```
>
> a = "I" b = "N"
>
> My output:
>
> ```
> [2, 1, 4, 2]
> ```
>
> Expected output:
>
> ```
> [2, 1, 3, 0]
> ```

I am using this method, because I need the x and y coordinate of the 2 elements separately as I use them later on.

Comment: If you have duplicated letters in your original list of lists, is that a problem?

Comment: There is something wrong with your `coords.insert`. The logic works properly ...

Comment: When you say "matrix" do you refer to a list of lists or a numpy array or something else? And what would be the output if an element is not unique?

Comment: @RichardKYu no there can't be any

Comment: @baskettaz yeah, the error is there I'll update the post

Comment: @Mr.T list of lists

Comment: Just for the fun , the numpy is here the right solution : `row, col = np.where(matrix == a)`

Comment: @Average_C_Enjoyer To mark the question as solved, accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether I have made any changes in input.  but, when I tried the code below, I got the expected output - [2,1,3,0]

```
coords = list()

matrix = [
    ['T', 'U', 'E', 'S', 'A'],
    ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G'], 
    ['H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M'], 
    ['N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R'],
    ['V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
]

a='I'
b='N'

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if(matrix[i][j] == a):
            coords.insert(0, i)
            coords.insert(1, j)
        if(matrix[i][j] == b):
            coords.insert(2, i)
            coords.insert(3, j)   

print(coords)
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, turns out the error is in the loop, not in the code I posted originally

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation.

```
a='E'
b="A"
lis=[]
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if matrix[i][j]==a:
            lis.extend([i,j])
        if matrix[i][j]==b:
            lis.extend([i,j])
        if len(lis)==4:
            break
    if len(lis)==4: # 4 means the length of the two coordinates is 4
        break
print(lis)
```